# Elementos no ocupan el total del espacio

Tags: html, css, html5

**Hice un modelo que voy a adjuntar en imagen en Adobe Illustrator, donde puse un titulo que separa secciones, pero no logro que use el mismo espacio, algun consejo? Adjunto el codigo con imagenes de como se ve y como deberia, si bien en las capturas se ve todo, solo necesito modificar la parte que dice 'Ultimas noticias...', la imagen de arriba es lo que tengo logrado y la de abajo como debe verse **

```
div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #002b87; padding: 0px;">
    <h1>Ultimas noticias del mundo boca</h1>
  </div>
  <br></br>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Antonio:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap);
body {
    font-family: 'Antonio', sans-serif;
}
.navbar-brand {
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: x-large;
}
.noticias {
    background-color: #002b87;
}
nav {
    background-color: #002b87;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #eeb125;
    font-family: sans-serif, helvetica;
}
nav li {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px, 20px;
}
nav a:hover {
    color: #eeb125;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button {
    background-color: #002b87;
    color: #eeb125;
    border-style: none;
}

.container {
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container ul li {
    list-style: none;
    width: max-content;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.slider {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}

ul.slider li {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    opacity: 0;
}

ul.slider li img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

ul.slider li:first-child {
    opacity: 1;
}

ul.slider li:target {
    opacity: 1;
}

.menu {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu li a{
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
p {
    color: #eeb125;
}
h1 {
    color: #eeb125;
}
label {
    color: #eeb125;
}
a {
    color: #eeb125;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[[image: Asi se ve por ahora, quiero que esa barra azul sobre el titulo de noticias sea mas grande que el texto en si]

[image: Asi deberia quedar]

los demas cambios se como hacerlos, solo necesito algo para solucionar lo del titulo de las noticias

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta, qué está mal? Código? Css?

Comment: Tu código html esta incompleto, y no proporcionaste el css, por favor modifica tu pregunta para que podamos observarlo mejor y darte una solución.

Comment: Ahi lo modifique agregando el css para que se entienda mejor y explique en mas dedtalle el problema